# Overlay line on Cartopy projection with n dots on line

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to overlay a line on a cartopy projection that is from specified point A to specified point B and then have the line have n=10 points along the path at a set interval. I do not currently have exact locations of where the points would lay, which is why I would want them to just be on a set interval length. The closest I have come is via setting x1 and y1 as nplinspace(start lat, endlat, npoints) and using matplotlib to overlay this. However, this draws a straight line and I want it to be curved (using transform=ccrs.Geodetic()). If I don't use np.linspace, I get the curve in the line I want, but only have two points on the line instead of 10. Is there a way to specify this type of line?

Here is my code currently (with only two points showing):

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-125,-60,15,65], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, color='lightgrey')

plt.plot([-120, -64], [20, 60],'o-', color='blue',  transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working on the points along a geodesic (or roughly greatcircle arc). The package `geographiclib` is handy for the determination of points along any geodesic. Here is a runnable code (and its output) that you may try and adjust to your need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
proj._threshold /= 20.  #allows fine grain plot

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)

ax.set_extent([-125,-60,15,65], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, color='lightgrey')

plt.plot([-120, -64], [20, 60], 'o-', color='blue',  transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

# start location
lon_fr = -120
lat_fr = 20
# end location
lon_to = -64
lat_to = 60

# This gets geodesic between the two points
# WGS84 ellipsoid is used
gl = Geodesic.WGS84.InverseLine(lat_fr, lon_fr, lat_to, lon_to)

num_points = 10  #for points on geodesic
print("distance latitude longitude azimuth")

# Compute points on the geodesic, and plot them as red dots
# gl.s13 is the total length of the geodesic
# the points are equally spaced by true distances, but not on the map
# due to the projection distortion
for ea in np.linspace(0, gl.s13, num_points):
    g = gl.Position(ea, Geodesic.STANDARD | Geodesic.LONG_UNROLL)
    print("{:.0f} {:.5f} {:.5f} {:.5f}".format(g['s12'], g['lat2'], g['lon2'], g['azi2']))
    lon2 = g['lon2']
    lat2 = g['lat2']
    ax.plot(lon2, lat2, "ro", transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The printout:

```
distance latitude longitude azimuth
0 20.00000 -120.00000 30.08493
692435 25.37542 -116.55578 31.41521
1384869 30.65898 -112.79470 33.18430
2077304 35.81710 -108.60549 35.48354
2769738 40.80499 -103.84610 38.43788
3462173 45.56121 -98.33485 42.21422
4154607 50.00000 -91.84447 47.02679
4847042 54.00165 -84.10986 53.12905
5539476 57.40348 -74.87293 60.76851
6231911 60.00000 -64.00000 70.06907
```

The plot:

[image: 10-points-on-geosdesic]

**Edit1**

In stead of specifying number of points (num_points=10) and get segments' length of 692,434.55 meters, you can specify the segment's length of your choice, say, 700,000 meters.

To achieve that, replace the line of code:

```
for ea in np.linspace(0, gl.s13, num_points):
```

with these lines:

```
dist_list = list(np.arange(0, gl.s13, 700000))
dist_list.append( gl.s13 ) #append distance to the last terminal point
for ea in dist_list:
```

```
    distance latitude longitude azimuth
    0       20.00000 -120.00000 30.08493
    700000  25.43370 -116.51657 31.43202
    1400000 30.77317 -112.70819 33.22849
    2100000 35.98357 -108.45940 35.56921
    2800000 41.01822 -103.62244 38.58436
    3500000 45.81281 -98.00784 42.44821
    4200000 50.27724 -91.37854 47.38444
    4900000 54.28538 -83.45933 53.65630
    5600000 57.66578 -73.98797 61.51518
    6231911 60.00000 -64.00000 70.06907
```

Comment: note that pyproj also provides a `geod` submodule that can do the exact same thing (and since cartopy already has pyproj as a dependency it would not require installing a new library!) .... for the above example using   `geod = proj.get_geod()`  and then `geod.inv_intermediate(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, 10)` should give you the same without the "geographiclib" library