# getting 6 equally spaced points from a sequence of linestring in python

Tags: geopandas, cartopy

I have data whose geometry is a sequence of line strings. From this geometry, we intend to obtain 6 equally spaced points. I have tried using the np.linspace and the np.arrange functions but I can't get what I am looking for. Kindly help me with the algorithm for working out this. Below is my geometry:

```
0  0    [(34.220545045730496, 4.442393531636864), (34.2224155889151, 4.441156322612342), (34.223315935853314, 4.440427900224906), (34.224077028342684, 4.4399257458670185), (34.224766879680814, 4.439278243976972), (34.22556405912324, 4.438776319912429), (34.226398022458866, 4.438165968807749), (34.22734024644533, 4.437556318146236), (34.22943852729713, 4.4365111090884435), (34.23209935027103, 4.435703837269645), (34.234239592861904, 4.434838866278886), (34.23690044724009, 4.434031568657816), (34.238982889400376, 4.4332242366641825), (34.24054473957206, 4.4327052342468), (34.244651946024526, 4.431263497605144), (34.246271748538476, 4.430629103905764), (34.24783374809697, 4.429764000807084), (34.24904866823832, 4.429014226798339), (34.25043718779403, 4.428091408213787), (34.2521728964003, 
   (34.352324364376926, 4.208738505912754), (34.35256435592366, 4.208668509240028)]

Name: geometry, type: object
```

I tried this code but still can't get the 25th ,75th pts right.

```
first_coord = N_df["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[0]) 
Point_25th = N_df['geometry'].agg(lambda g: np.percentile(g, 25)) 
center_point = N_df['geometry'].centroid 
point_75th = N_df['geometry'].agg(lambda g: np.percentile(g, 75)) 
last_coord = N_df["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[-1]) 
N_df["start_coord"] = first_coord 
N_df["25th percentile"] = Point_25th 
N_df["Midpoint"] = center_point 
N_df["75th percentile"] = point_75th 
N_df["last_coord"] = last_coord 

# N_df ...?
```

Comment: ?? Each linestring has 6 equally spaced vertices (terminal points included). Distances are measured along great-circle arcs.

Comment: Is this what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561086/overlay-line-on-cartopy-projection-with-n-dots-on-line/62578476#62578476

Comment: @swatchai the above link is close to what i want but now, i am unable to itterate through all the rows producing the 6 points given that each row has a different length

Comment: please edit your question and add relevant code to show that you have attempted to tackle the problem and stuck.

Comment: I triedthiscode but still can't get the 25th ,75th ptsright first_coord= N_df["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[0])
Point_25th=N_df['geometry'].agg(lambda g: np.percentile(g, 25))
center_point=N_df['geometry'].centroid
point_75th=N_df['geometry'].agg(lambda g: np.percentile(g, 75))                                       
last_coord=N_df["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[-1])

N_df["start_coord"] = first_coord
N_df["25th percentile"]= Point_25th
N_df["Midpoint"]= center_point
N_df["75th percentile"] = point_75th
N_df["last_coord"]= last_coord
N_df